# Root URL Location of Flex BlazeDS Project

Tags: java, apache-flex

In my Flex/BlazeDS application I'm trying to read a properties file to load database connection settings. Where should I keep this file (the location) in my project so that I can read the file as in Client Server architecture.

I tried to write a new file into the server root location

```
new FileOutputStream("OracleSettings.properties")
```

but the file was never created. I refreshed my Project, explored through Windows Explorer and Searched through Search Engine but was unable to locate OracleSettings.properties file.

How to include this file into project properties so that Eclipse will also export this file into the output folder of the application???

I use Eclipse with FlashBuilder 4.6 Plugin
I created a Flex Project with Server type Java and loaded BlazeDS war file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`FlexContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` is your web application root location.